# Get field by ID from Firebase database (Firestore) using Angular and Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the name of the document by using the DocumentID in Firestore/Firebase. but i get i crush in the app.

my html code:

```
<ion-label>  
<ion-icon ios="ios-pin" md="md-pin"></ion-icon>
 {{ getCityName(item.data().cityOfPost) }}
</ion-label>
```

by the way: **item.data().cityOfPost** is a valid variable which holds the ID of the city.

the function:

```
getCityName(value: any){
  firebase.firestore().collection("cities").doc(value).get().then((docs) => {
   return docs.data().cityName; 
   }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
   })
}
```

**docs.data().cityName** is supposed to get the **cityName** field witch hold the city name in the **cities** table

I will be very greatfull if someone can help me with this.

Thank you,

Comment: If the app crashes there should be an error message. What is the exact error message?

Comment: actually there are error messages in the console. I looked again,  it seems that its looping infinitely !

Comment: The code you shared contains no loop, so it must be elsewhere. I'd recommend trying to isolate the problem. For more on this, see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are your "*ngFor="let item of list" async? Maybe your problem is the callback of the list and the item.data() is not ready to use in your function.

Comment: yes my function is async. i tries to remove the async but it doesnt work  :( what should i do ?